# What is the best/recommended way to start and stop FlowReceiver in J2EE/JEE application?

Tags: solace

What is the best place to start/stop Solace listener which subscribes to a topic. Is it ok to create/initialize connection in PostConstruct and close it in PreDestroy methods?
In all the examples I see CountDownLatch is used to read just 'n' message, whereas  I need to listen for all the messages .

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the Solace JCSMP API? 
If so, what you are suggesting makes sense. Create the session once and re-use it while your app is running. Don't tear it down and set it back up per message

Comment: Thanks @Mrc0113 do you have any sample code without Spring libraries and Countdownlatch?

Comment: Hi @Shan - check out the samples in this directory and see if they'll help you out. These samples show how to implement common pattern actors.